# Skew TextView Text in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Hi,

I want set TextView text as given in image, is it possible in android.

Comment: Typically, questions with a yes/no answer aren't a good fit for this site. You should show some research effort on your part and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have seen this question before. [Here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375130/skewing-a-text-view-in-android)